# "Evaluate" a c# string

Tags: c#

I am reading a C# source file.
When I encounter a string, I want to get it's value.
For instance, in the following example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {
    string fileName = "C:\\Temp\\A Weird\"FileName";
  }
}
```

I would like to retrieve

```
C:\Temp\A Weird"FileName
```

Is there an existing procedure to do that?
Coding a solution with all the possible cases should be quite tricky (@, escape sequences. ...).
I am convinced such procedure exists...
I would like to have the dual function too (to inject a string into a C# source file)

Thanks in advance.
Philippe

P.S:
I gave an example with a filename, but I look for a solution working for all kinds of strings.

Comment: so you want all string variables?

Comment: @"C:\Temp\A Weird FileName"; and than insert the " between Weird FileName.

Comment: Are you looking for `Path.GetFullPath(fileName)`?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? A typical approach in language dependent strings is handling them separately. In your code that would be string fileName = MyStringBundle["TheWeirdFileNameString"], and then would StringBundle have all its strings stored with IDs in dedicated string files.

Comment: Use Microsoft Roslyn and deep dive into the it :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769.aspx#Toc306015689

Comment: You just need a regex that will get you everything between " (inverted commas), unless its the one preceeded by backslash, like in your example

Comment: @dark_ruby, unless you have a string like `var str = @"Hello ""World""";`

Comment: @dcastro agree, you could be using greedy regex, that will include all your inverted commas to the last one, actually closing a string (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can use CodeDOM to read a C# code file and parse its elements. It generates a code tree, and then you can look for nodes representing `strings`.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2502/C-CodeDOM-parser

Other CodeDom parsers:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14383/An-Expression-Parser-for-CodeDom

NRefactory: https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of extracting these strings using a regular expression:

```
  ("(\\"|[^"])*")
```

This particular one works on your simple example and gives the filename (complete with leading and trailing quote characters); whether it would work on more complex ones I can't easily tell unfortunately.

For clarity, `(\\"|[^"])` matches any character apart from `"`, *except* where it has a leading `\` character.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `".*"` Regex to match all string values, then remove trailing inverted commas and unescape it.

this will allow `\"` and `""` characters inside your string

so both `"C:\\Temp\\A Weird\"FileName"` and `"Hello ""World"""` will match